# How can I round numbers up instead of down?

Tags: c#

I'm performing some calculations and inserting the result into a database.

My problem is, that the answers I'm getting seem to be rounding down rather than up. This might not seem important but over the course of a lot of sales, the cents start adding up!!

```
Decimal pubCut = rrp * (percentageCutD / 100);
Decimal retCut = rrp * retailerCut;
Decimal edcut = rrp * edpercentage;
```

I'll be honest, I'm rubbish with figures and the whole Maths function was something I tried to avoid in college. Can anyone tell me how I can get these figures to round up as opposed to down?

Comment: Can you please post the types of `rrp`, `percentageCutD`, `retailerCut` and `edpercentage`?

Comment: Apologies, they are all decimal.

Comment: "the whole Maths function was something I tried to avoid in college". Back to college in that case, as this lack of knowledge will haunt you for the rest of your working life.

Comment: Your question seem to imply that C# will always round down when in fact C# will do "proper" rounding up or down to the nearest integer. A rounding problem may not necessarily be solved by always rounding up and if your problem is that the parts don't add up to the whole rounding up may introduce a new problem where the parts add up to more than the whole.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`Math.Ceiling()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) method.

```
double[] values = {7.03, 7.64, 0.12, -0.12, -7.1, -7.6};
Console.WriteLine("  Value          Ceiling          Floor\n");
foreach (double value in values)
   Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1,16} {2,14}", 
                     value, Math.Ceiling(value), Math.Floor(value));
// The example displays the following output to the console:
//         Value          Ceiling          Floor
//       
//          7.03                8              7
//          7.64                8              7
//          0.12                1              0
//         -0.12                0             -1
//          -7.1               -7             -8
//          -7.6               -7             -8
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is this

```
(percentageCutD / 100)
```

Since 100 is an int, it will perform integer division, so that 150/100 becomes 1. You can fix this by maksing sure that 100 is a decimal since you want a decimal as result in the end. Change your code to.

```
(percentageCutD / 100D)
```

However, if you always want to round values even like 1.1 up to 2, then you will have to use `Math.Ceiling` to accomplish this. If you for some reason want to avoid the `Math` class (I can't see why you want to do it, you can add 1 to the result and cast it to an `int` to effectively round up to the nearest integer.

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen - Integer division will only occur if `percentageCutD` is also an Integer. As it stands there is not enough information in the question.

Comment: if percentageCutD is of type double or decimal then the devision will be fine

Comment: and then use Math.Ceiling() to round up :)

Comment: I just assumed that it was an int because the OP said that it rounded down, and he hasn't written any code to round up or down at all. So my assumption then was that there is an integer division going on here. But I might of course be wrong. The OP can conirm this hopefully.

Comment: percentageCutD is of type Decimal. I'll use Math.Ceiling(). Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

.Net's Math.Round function uses something commonly referred to as banker's rounding which works by rounding .5 to the nearest even integer, ie  22.5 = 22 and 23.5 = 24. This gives a more even distribution when rounding.

It's also worth noting the SQL server doesn't use bankers rounding

Answer (score 1):

Your incoming percentages probably don't add to 100 %. Compute one of your fractions by substracting the sum of the other fractions from the total.

```
var v = 100D;
var p1 = 33D/100;
var p2 = 33D/100;
var p3 = 33D/100;
var v1 = p1*v;
var v2 = p2*v;
var v3 = p3*v;
var sum = v1 + v2 + v3;
```

Unfortunately `sum` is 99 and not 100.

You can compute `v3` like this instead:

```
var v3 = v - (v1 + v2);
```

Or better fix the rounding error in the incoming percentages: